# Solving an equation with a maximum variable

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I've the following equation that I need to solve:

```
Solve[{((400 f π r x - 1000000 C3 f^3 π^3 r^3 x^2)^2 + (1 - 
        20000 f^2 π^2 r^2 x (C3 + x))^2)/((4000 f π r x - 
        1000000000 C3 f^3 π^3 r^3 x^2)^2 + (1 - 
        2000000 f^2 π^2 r^2 x (C3 + x))^2) == 10^((-s)/(10)), 
  1/(√((8 f π r x - 8 C3 f^3 π^3 r^3 x^2)^2 + (1 - 
          8 f^2 π^2 r^2 x (C3 + x))^2)) == 1/Sqrt[2], 
  x > 0 && C3 > 0 && 10000 <= r <= 100000 && 0 < C3 < 3 x && 
   10^(-12) < x <= 500*10^(-6) && 10^(-12) < C3 <= 1000*10^(-6)}, {C3,
   r, x}]
```

There is one thing given and that is $f$. Now I need to solve that equation, but $s$ needs to be at his maximum ($s\in\mathbb{R}^+)$. How can I solve that equation using the maximum value for $s$ possible?